# Turning off integrated in PHPUnit Symfony/Yaml Component

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, yaml

PHPUnit has integrated Symfony/Yaml Component and loads it by simple 'require' command so it can't be managed by an autoloader.

This component has old version and causes problems when phpunit used in a Symfony2 framework.

Any ideas how to make phpunit use appropriate Symfony/Yaml component? I can just remove it from the phar archive, but it's weak solution.

Comment: I see that Symfony/Yaml component has PHPUnit tests. If they run tests phpunit will tests its own yaml component instead real one.

Comment: Are you installing phpunit globally?

Comment: I use phpunit.phar but it doesn't metter. It uses 'require' command instead autoloader.

Comment: That is not what I am asking.  On a per application basis, you can install phpunit in the vendor directory and run it using vendor/bin/phpunit.  If you do this then the dependency issue will go away.  I suspect you have phpunit installed globally which can lead to dependency issues.